# How to properly highlight a code block (in-buffer) when inside of another block/environment?

Tags: org-mode, latex, syntax-highlighting

The issue is that my source code blocks, `BEGIN_src ... END_src`, are not properly highlighted when within another block, e. g., `BEGIN_proof ... END_proof`. Here is a picture of how that looks like:

[image]

Observe how the second code block within the proof environment is not highlighted properly?

This is just an example of the problem. The real problem is that I have a `homework.cls` Latex class that I use with orgmode. The structure of that class in latex looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{homework}
\author{Student}

\begin{document} \maketitle

  \begin{question}
  ...
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
  ...
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
  ...
  \end{question}

  ...

\end{document}
```

This as an org file looks like this,

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: homework
#+AUTHOR: Student

#+BEGIN_question
...
#+END_question

#+BEGIN_question
...
#+END_question

#+BEGIN_question
...
#+END_question

...
```

See now if I want to have a code block within a question, it is not properly highlighted just like it is not in the proof environment (see the picture above).

I am using `doom-themes` Here are my (what i think to be) relevant org mode configs:

```lisp
;; org-mode
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :pin org
  :custom
  (org-log-done 'time "orgmode.org/manual/Closing-items.html")
  (org-support-shift-select t "Support selection with shift key")
  (org-export-with-toc nil "Suppress table of contents")
  (org-src-fontify-natively t "Fontify code in code blocks")
  (org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "listings" "xcolor")) "For code listings")
  (org-preview-latex-default-process 'org-xdv-to-svg)
  (org-babel-python-command "python3")
  ;; (org-latex-with-hyperref nil "Don't insert hypersetup in preamble")
  :config
  (define-key cua-global-keymap [C-return] 'conditional-C-return)
  (add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist org-xdv-to-svg)
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((python . t))))
```

This is already a pretty long post, so if I can make it better by adding or taking away details, let me know. In case it's needed, [here](https://github.com/simurgh9/emacs786/blob/master/init.el) is my config file. You can find the org configs by `Ctrl-f` and typing `;; org-mode`.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried loading the above file with no configs like this `emacs -q filename.org`. The results were the same, i. e., the nested source block was not highlighted. So maybe orgmode just does not support that?